# A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that is larger than $\mathcal{L}$ such that outer measure is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{S})$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-measure

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The author wrote as follows on p.52 in this book:

> We have accomplished the major goal of this section, which was to show that outer measure restricted to Borel sets is a measure. As we will see in this subsection, outer measure is actually a measure on a somewhat larger class of sets called the Lebesgue measurable sets.

Is there a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that outer measure is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{S})$ and $\mathcal{L}\subsetneq\mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Under certain set-theoretic assumptions, all sets are Lebesgue measurable, and you can't get any bigger than that. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon ... this is irrelevant. Math texts like Axler assume the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: You may be interested in reading my detailed answer in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400503/caratheodory-criterion-sufficient-but-is-it-necessary/1740815#1740815

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a certain sense, no.

Write $\lambda^*$ for Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R$.  Suppose $\lambda^*$ is a measure on $\mathcal S \supsetneq \mathcal L$.  Let $E \in \mathcal S \setminus \mathcal L$.  Now
$$
E = \bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \big([-M,M]\cap E\big) .
$$
So there is $M > 0$ so that $E \cap [-M,M]$ is not Lebesgue measurable.  But then
$$
\lambda^*\big([-M,M]\cap E\big) + \lambda^*\big([-M,M]\setminus E\big) < \lambda^*\big([-M,M]\big) .
$$
All three of these sets belong to $\mathcal S$, and thus $\lambda^*$ is not a measure on $\mathcal S$.

---

There is still the possibility of $\mathcal S \supsetneq \mathcal L$ and a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal S$ that agrees with Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal L$.  It is just that $\mu$ isn't Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: GEdgar, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Note: "thanks" comments are discouraged here, and on all stackexchange forums.